# Process Builder limitations

Tags: process-builder, process

I tried to update values on account object which is a parent object but I could not find the 'type' field which is a picklist anywhere in immediate actions. Basically I want to change the 'type' field value on account object which is a picklist when there is change in 'service status' picklist field on a custom object.

please help!!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access Account object fields using the lookp field for the Account on the object process builder is run on. For example, to access Account fields from the contact object you can use the AccountID lookup as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Process Builder has following limitations only:

> - Make sure that your processes aren’t set up to create infinite loops. For example, if an Update Records action for Process1 triggers
>     Process2 and a Create a Record action for Process2 triggers Process1,
>     the looping might cause your organization to exceed its hourly
>     limits.
> - If you create processes to replace any workflow rules, make sure you delete those workflow rules when you activate the equivalent
>     processes. Otherwise, both workflow rules and processes will fire and
>     cause unexpected results, such as overwritten records or redundant
>     email messages.
> - If you create processes to replace any Apex triggers, make sure you delete those Apex triggers when you activate the equivalent
>     processes. Otherwise, both workflow and processes will fire and cause
>     unexpected results, such as overwritten records or redundant email
>     messages.
> - A process name must be 255 characters or fewer.
> - A process’s API name must be 77 characters or fewer.
> - Each process is associated with a single object.
> - If you have processes on converted leads and want to update the records that result from the conversion, you must enable the lead
>     setting Enable Validation and Triggers from Lead Convert.
> - You can’t change the order of the criteria nodes or the order of the actions. After you add criteria nodes and actions, the only way to
>     reorder them is to delete them and start over.
> - Actions are executed in the order in which they appear in the Process Builder.
> - If any of the actions fail, the entire transaction fails and an error message displays. For example, a Post to Chatter action fails if
>     the Chatter group that it tries to post to is private. For details,
>     see Troubleshooting Your Processes.
> - If a single action group includes multiple “Update Records” actions that apply different values to the same field, the last
>     action’s value is used.
> - Processes that update owners don’t also transfer associated items. To ensure transfer, use one “Update Records” action for each type of
>     child record that you want to transfer. For example, if you’re using a
>     process to transfer an account to a new owner, use one action to
>     update all the child contacts, one to update all the child
>     opportunities, one to update all the child contracts, and so on.
> - If your organization uses multiple currencies, currency fields are updated using the record's currency. If you choose to update a field
>     based on a formula, any values in your formula are interpreted in the
>     currency of the record.
> - Email alerts aren’t supported for task- or event-based processes.

Check field permission and review your process builder Action criteria to make sure that you are targeting correct object form the child object. In addition check field permissions. Process builder display field which makes sense to Action with criteria you selected.